# Почему тут стоит запятая

Tags: пунктуация

В титрах к немому фильму "Броненосец "Потемкин" есть фраза "Собака, и та есть не будет". Но почему тут стоит запятая после слова "собака"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я думаю, что в этом предложении используется усилительная частица, равная по значению и функции частице ДАЖЕ. Ср.: ***Даже*** собака есть не будет. Запятую поэтому ставить не нужно: ***Собака и та есть не будет.***